# R.drawable being replaced with android.R.drawable

Tags: android

I am following a video tutorial for Android Studio that tells me to enter this line:

```
public class customswipeadapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private int[] image_resources = {R.drawable.picture};
}
```

Everything is good until I try to enter the `R.drawable` Android Studio only offers the suggestion `android.R.drawable` which is then flagged as an error.

How can I solve this?

Comment: what is that error?

Comment: check out this tutorial and implement it. https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imageview-example/

Answer (score 1):

This happens sometimes when your android studio has **Imports on the fly** :P. To configure your Android studio use [this](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/configuring-android-studio-4aa4f54f1153) link. And also do this steps,

Go to settings->Editors->General->Auto Import

In JAVA uncheck *Optimize import on fly*, and *Add unambiguous imports on fly*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use both `R.drawable.picture` and `android.R.drawable`. Android Studio support both. So if you want to use `R.drawable.picture` just simply type but remember in your `drawable` folder  image name `picture` must be save.

Answer (score 0):

In you project directory, there should be a file called 'res'. If you right click on that and select `new Android Resource Directory`, it'll take you to another window. From here, change resource type to show `drawable`, and click `OK`. Now, put whatever image you would like to draw into drawable, and you should be good to reference it in your code like you were trying to do.

I've had some issues with this in the past, and once or twice I just had to restart Android Studio. Rebuilding the project may also work, but I've had better luck with a simple restart.